# Two or more pop3 email accounts

Tags: emacs, gnus

I've been using 'gnus' in emacs for several weeks now, but haven't found any solution to the problems of multiple pop3 accounts. I have this section in my '.gnus.el' -

```
(setq mail-sources '((file :path "/var/mail/boudiccas")
                     (pop :server "mail.talktalk.net"          
                          :user "boztu@talktalk.net"
                          :password "custardcreams")                 
                     (pop :server "pop.mail.yahoo.com"
                          :user "winnie@yahoo.com"
                          :password "rhubarbpie")))
```

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be connecting. How should it be shown in the '.gnus.el' please? I have four pop3 accounts to use if I could only find out how to use multiple pop3 mailboxes.

Comment: Here is a link to two different functions -- one for work and one for home -- perhaps it can point you in the right direction:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.emacs.gnus/G9SR6cRc9gw/LUzzf8MKIaYJ  You may wish to edit your question so that it is not closed -- e.g., as to the title and "taking an awful long time to connect", which implies that you **are** eventually connecting.

Comment: By keeping the stackoverflow tag of `pop3` in your question, you are likely reaching the wrong target audience as the people who use Emacs and Gnus are more likely to be able to understand where you are coming from, and thus are more likely to provide a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks, amended as per your suggestions.

Comment: Is this resolved? If not - what happens if you just try to connect to one of the pop servers, does it work? From looking at [https://help.yahoo.com/kb/pop-server-settings-sln4724.html] it looks as though at least Yahoo! requires _apop_ authentication (see mail-sources docs in gnus info).